# Prove connectedness of topological space with continuous mappings

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

We provide $\{0,1\}$ with the discrete topology $\{\emptyset, \{0\},\{1\},\{0,1\}\}$. Show that $(X,\tau)$ is connected if and only if there are exactly two continuous maps from $(X,\tau)$ to $\{0,1\}$.

Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Which two continuous functions always exist to any space with two points?

Comment: The identity function and ....?

Comment: The identity is only from a space to itself. No I meant constant maps, tehy are always continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: if $f:X\to \left\{0,1\right\}$ is a function, then
$$X=f^{-1}\left(\left\{0\right\}\right)\cup f^{-1}\left(\left\{1\right\}\right)$$